# sonar link is routing to localhost:9000 .not working with IP how to change it

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

When sonar is run by the jenkins then there is one sonar link is available.
I click on the link gets sonar Dashboard open at localhost:9000.However,this approach is not working when some one open this jenkins setup by browser like IP:9000 then it comes localhost:9000 which is not desired because setup is not on that machine which has accessed by browser.

How this can be fixed

How can I come from this problem

while I tried by doing some change in sonar-runner.properties sonar.host.url=http:IP
which is not work.
I changed in sonar.properties.
sonar.web.host=IP

both the solution is not working.

Expected http://IP:9000 actual http://localhost:9000

Which is not working when accessed by some another machine.

Comment: Maybe some firewall is blocking the access to port 9000?

Comment: When I run manually by putting the http://IP:9000. it works.

if firewall is blocking . it should not work even.